# SublimeText3 Evaluate in REPL according to programming language?

Tags: python, r, sublimetext3, read-eval-print-loop

I'm currently using SublimeText3 and R for my data analysis work.  I simply open an R-REPL in Sublime Text and press `CNTRL+Enter` from a written script to evaluate a line of code.  I would like to do this same process with Python, but when I try to send the Python script to the open Python REPL using `CTRL+Enter`, I receive the error "Cannot find REPL for R."

I believe this has something to do with my default path for the REPL in my user settings,

```
"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.0\\bin\\x64"}
```

However, I don't know how to generalize this to work with multiple environments.  It would be very convenient for me to have Python and R scripts open and be able to send commands to their respective windows.

How do I fix this?